# Stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, rowcount

**Q**:How to stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected in PostgreSQL?

**Database** : PostgreSQL

**Version**:  9.3

Comment: That feedback is shown by the SQL **client tool**, not "by Postgres". Are you using `psql` or some other other tool?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, psql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the meta command `\pset footer off`:

```
psql (9.3.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> select 42;
 ?column?
----------
       42
(1 row)

postgres=> \pset footer off
Default footer is off.
postgres=> select 42;
 ?column?
----------
       42

postgres=>
```

If you want to make this permanent, you can put that command into your `~/.psqlrc`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN88713